# What is the meaning of the phrase: "take huge leaps forward with"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

To be specific, I don't understand the meaning of the word "with". Here is a sentence:

> "Manufacturing innovation takes huge leaps forward **with** the 3rd generation Anaconda printing machine."

Manufacturing innovation is better because/thanks to 3rd generation Anaconda printing machines? Or, is it the opposite?

Comment: "the 3rd generation Anaconda printing machine" helps "manufacturing innovation" take huge leaps forward.

Comment: Yes, like you said, technology is better because of the new printing machine, but also the new printing machine itself is better technology. The new machine is itself a leap forward, and also causes other technology in the sector to take leaps forward. That's why "with" is used here instead of "because of" or "thanks to".

Comment: okey, thank you for your help :)